# Disable first-run page in AbBlock Plus For Google Chrome in Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, google-chrome-extension, adblock

I have installed Adblock Plus in an ubuntu docker image. However, I dont want the first-run page to appear when I first start Chrome inside the docker container. Is there any non-interactive way to prevent this?

Any leads are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to using the steps outlined on this link.  I've done it successfully on Windows, but not Ubuntu or while running Docker.

https://adblockplus.org/development-builds/suppressing-the-first-run-page-on-chrome

Good luck.